# Linear Regression on Multiindex Pandas Dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, regression, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to perform a regression of annual temperatures over time, and obtain a slope/linear trend (number generated by the regression) for each latitude and longitude coordinate (the full dataset has many lat/lon locations). I want to replace the year and temp for each location with this slope value. My end goal is to map these trends with cartopy.

Here is some test data in a pandas multi index dataframe

```
                     tempanomaly
lat     lon     time_bnds   
-89.0   -179.0  1957    0.606364
                1958    0.495000
                1959    0.134286
```

this is my goal:

```
lat     lon      trend  
-89.0   -179.0   -0.23604
```

this is my regression function

```
def regress(y):
    #X is the year or index, y is the temperature
    X=np.array(range(len(y))).reshape(len(y),1)
    y = y.array
    fit = np.polyfit(X, y, 1)
    return (fit[0])
```

and here is how I'm attempting to call it

```
reg = df.groupby(["lat", "lon"]).transform(regress)
```

The error I'm receiving is `TypeError: Transform function invalid for data types`.
In the debugging process, I found that the regression was running for each line (3 times, using the test data), as opposed to once for each location (only one location is in the test data). I believe the problem lies in the method I'm using to call the regression, but can't figure out another way to iterate through and perform a regression by lat/lon pairs—I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have also error in your `regress` function because in your case `X` should be 1D vector. So here it is the fixed `regress` function:

```
def regress(y):
    #X is the year or index, y is the temperature
    X = np.array(range(len(y)))
    y = y.array
    fit = np.polyfit(X, y, 1)
    return (fit[0])
```

> For `pandas.DataFrame.transform` produced DataFrame will have same axis length as self. [Pandas Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html)

Therefore `aggregate` is a better option for your case.

```
reg = df.groupby(["lat", "lon"]).aggregate(trend=pd.NamedAgg('tempanomaly', regress)).reset_index()
```

which produces:

```
lat    lon    trend
-89.0  -179.0  -0.236039
```

with the sample data created as follows:

```
lat_lon = [(-89.0, -179.0), (-89.0, -179.0), (-89.0, -179.0)]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(lat_lon, names=["lat", "lon"])
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'time_bnds':[1957,1958,1959], 
    'tempanomaly': [0.606364, 0.495000, 0.134286]
},index=index)
```